# Corona: How to send multiple files on server in corona SDK?

Tags: file-upload, httpwebrequest, webserver, coronasdk, network-protocols

I want to send multiple files to server some of which are audio,images and plain text files.

I am trying to put all the file name in single table and sending that table over the sever. Can we achieve this? How?

I was able to send simple string using this link:
[network.request](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html#custom-http-headers)